# how to insert values into DB using procedure

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

i have already created one procedure named as SET and i am trying to send values to it through java somewhat like this.

```
stmt.executeQuery("call set("+id+",'"+name+"','"+sal+"','"+dept+"')");
```

as name,sal and dept are in String format.

but i am getting error.

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set(12,'D','12','cse')' at line 1

Comment: It should be `{call ....}`. See the JDBC tutorial for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"set" is [reserve word in Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) so it might be the problem of your troubles. General advice is to avoid reserve words and named your procedures meaningfully (setAccountRecrod for example).

When I've managed to create procedure with that name I have to call it with escaped name (with back tick):

```
stmt.executeQuery("call `set`("+id+",'"+name+"','"+sal+"','"+dept+"')");
```

but as suggested it is better to use `prepareCall` like that:

```
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall("call `set`(" + id + ",'" + 
     name + "','" + sal + "','" + dept + "')");
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

or even better:

```
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall("call `set`(?,?,?,?)");
callableStatement.setInt(1, id);
callableStatement.setString(2, name);
callableStatement.setString(3, sal);
callableStatement.setString(4, dept);
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

All of above worked for me on latest version of MariaDb when I've create procedure like that:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `set`;

CREATE PROCEDURE `set` (IN id INT, name VARCHAR(25), sal VARCHAR(25), dept VARCHAR(25)) 
BEGIN
SELECT VERSION();
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the stored procedure through CallableStatement as shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-in-parameter-example/)

Good luck